# Force content generated by javascript to reveal itself

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I'm generating some content through an API, accessed by javascript, and I cannot grab the source code of what is plainly displayed, post-load, on the browser. I can highlight the text and view the source of selected text (which is a firefox feature), but I will be using CURL to capture the data automatically with php... How can I capture the data? Is there a way to update the source(maybe through a DOM update) so it displays some how? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there are plenty of tools to let you debug and examine the source, it all depends on what browser you are using

Comment: Sorry, confusing question. You have a page that generates some content using Javascript, and you want to see that dynamically generated content when fetching the page via cURL?

Comment: Yes, so any manual display technique is not what I'm needing. I need javascript or jquery solution.

Comment: You can't use a JavaScript or jQuery solution — you're using PHP/Curl, not a web browser with an embedded JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just request some HTML source and expect the results of modifying it with JS to be in place without running the JS so if you want to get the content in PHP, then you will have to either

1. Push the HTML through something that will execute the JavaScript (I'd probably look to [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) if I were using Perl, it uses [Mozrepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki). I don't know if PHP has a similar nice API for it)
2. Reverse engineer the JavaScript and do whatever it does to get the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull up the page source using Google Chrome from within developer tools (wrench in the top right -> Tools -> Developer tools, or Control+Shift+I (that's an uppercase i)). The source code shown in the developer tools represents the up-to-date source code of the page, including things that were generated dynamically by JavaScript after the page initially loads.

I'm sure other browsers have similar capabilities, I just happen to know Chrome's method off the top of my head.

Comment: Fork the necessary bits and pieces out of webkit and V8 and compile the thing. In other words, the easiest way would be to provide a "pre-rendered" fall back for things that do not support JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you developing environment is Linux/Unix, you could incorporate [PjantonJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a very nifty tool that executes the JavaScript and it passes the output. The way I would recommend doing this would be with a `shell_exec()` in witch you run you CLI PhantomJS.

Hope this helps.